# Rails use request.url in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a view this code works fine:

```
<% if request.url.include?('ndeavor2s.com') %>
    <p>Staging</p>
<% end %>
```

But, in mailers/comment_mailer.rb this code doesn't:

```
if request.url.include?('ndeavor2s.com')
 fromurl = "@mail.ndeavor2s.com"
end
```

I get:

undefined local variable or method `request'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is an action controller thing, not available in action mailer directly.  If you need, just pass the `request` object into the mailer object when you instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks! - what would be the best method to pass the data?

Comment: Pass it in as an argument to your mailer object when you create it just like you do any other parameter  `foo = Mailer.my_email(request).deliver`

Comment: If I wanted to use it in more places, could I set it in helper/application.helper.rb ??

Comment: No,helpers arent available by default. Depending on your version of rails you could just include/extend the helper into your mailer, but I dont really see any point/benefit in doing so